# React: how to setData and then post?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an issue where I think the existing state of a component is being posted via fetch before it has been updated.

This is the function called when submit is clicked:

```
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const html = convertToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent());
    setData((current) => [...current, { name: name, content: html }]);
    fetch("/api2", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ parcel: data }),
    });
  }
```

I think `data` is being posted before it has been updated via `setData`.

How do I get the `POST` method to action after `data` has been updated?

Comment: You don't have to wait until `data` has been updated, for you already know what data is. Try `const updatedData =[...data,{ name: name, content: html }]; setData(updatedData); fetch("/api2",{ method: "POST",
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ parcel: updatedData })})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the state is an async operation, and the new state would only be available on the next render. Post the new `data` to the api in a `useEffect` block dependent on the `data` state.

Note: you'll also need to avoid posting on moutn (as noted by 
[bbbbbbbboat's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74157384/react-how-to-setdata-and-then-post/74157413#comment130930116_74157413)). For that you can add a boolean ref the will enable you to skip the mount phase.

```
const mounted = useRef(false);

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const html = convertToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent());
  setData((current) => [...current, { name: name, content: html }]);
}

useEffect(() => {
  if(mounted.current) {
    fetch("/api2", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ parcel: data }),
    });
  } else {
    mounted.current = true;
  }
}, [data]);
```

Since you're using `data` directly when posting, you can also create a temp `data`, and update both the state and the api:

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const html = convertToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent());
  const tempData = [...data, { name: name, content: html }];

  setData(tempData);

  fetch("/api2", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ parcel: tempData }),
  });
}
```

Comment: It may send request on mount, maybe it is unexpected behavior.